# Add text when press return in wpf TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox Which have AcceptsReturn = True . When the user press return the new line  will already have as the first letter "-".
How do I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Subscribe to TextBox `KeyDown` event and detect if `Enter` is pressed:

**XAML**:

```
<TextBox ... KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
```

**C#**:

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
        txtBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "-"; //add new line and "-"
        txtBox.CaretIndex = txtBox.Text.Length;   //caret to the end
    }
}
```

To use this method you'll have to `false` `Accept Return` property.

Comment: when u have AcceptsReturn setted on true, key down not firing when enter is pressed ...

Comment: I've mentioned there, you'll have to `false` it to use this method.

Comment: OP wants to add a new line with `-` at the start. That was his approach to do it, I've provided another one. You should down vote when the solution is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: Red first sentence - "I have a TextBox Which have AcceptsReturn = True"

Comment: I suppose the solution is correct. Every problem has a lot of solutions. You have your's, I have mine. Lets end it here and let the OP take his decision.

Answer (score 1):

Hook on `PreviewKeyDown` event :

```
<TextBox PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnKeyDown"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         x:Name="TextBox"
</TextBox>


private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // what u need
        // TextBox.Text += "-";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: write a method that detects a press of the "Return" key on the Key Press.
Step 2: add a "-" to the TextBox's `.text`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be other smarter ways to do this but a simple solution would be add a PreviewKeyDown to the TextBox. (Note: with accepts return KeyDown is not triggered its handled by the text box.)

```
PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"

 private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if(e.Key == Key.Return)
      {
          (sender as TextBox).Text += "-";
      }
 }
```

This should add a - in the new line.